# What causes these background distortions in a bubble chamber? I see these in many fermi labs images

Tags: particle-physics

[image]

What causes these background distortions in a bubble chamber?  I see these in many fermi labs images.  I'm assuming the circle could be a piston or some sort of diaphram to help with pressure control.  Also I typically see much larger circular background images which could be just lighting effects from the pressure vessel housing?  Any thoughts?

Comment: Seems to me to be a straightforward question on data from physics experiments that only a particle physicist could adequately answer. Experimental physics questions don't get much love around here...

Comment: *Experimental physics questions don't get much love around here...*  and more is the pity.

Comment: The “background distortions” are due to the effects of the edges of the lenses which are used to illuminate the bubble chamber. Look at [Figure 1.1](http://etheses.dur.ac.uk/10254/1/10254_7048.PDF?UkUDh:CyT).

Comment: As in the above picture is obvious it is an optical effect of the recording on the film, because the tracks are not affected, it is not fluid motion. I have looked at thousands of pictures of the two meter chamber, which did not have the above problem https://cds.cern.ch/record/2307419?ln=en

Comment: if you take the trouble to peruse this site https://hst-archive.web.cern.ch/archiv/HST2005/bubble_chambers/BCwebsite/index.htm you will see the the next bubble chamber at cern has some such optical  effects. They do not affect the measurements